# MONGO - Know if all elements of input array is in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem with mongo query. I have the next colecction.

```
"id" : "TEST"
"client" : "0048948",
"contracts" : [
    {
        "contractNumberId" : "contractNumber1",
        "otherField" : "XXXXX",
        "contractFormats" : [
            {
                "formatId" : "format12"
            },
            {
                "formatId" : "format10"
            }
        ]
    },{
        "contractNumberId" : "contractNumber2",
        "otherField" : "XXXXX",
        "contractFormats" : [
            {
                "formatId" : "format12"
            },
            {
                "formatId" : "format15"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

And I want to search if I have a collection in which I have all the values ​​of an array of contracts or formats that are passed to me. For example if in my input I have the next contracts or formats [contractNumber1, format15] My query should return true because I found it in my database, in contracts or format, but if for example mi inputs was [contractNumbe1, format50, contract3, 10], my query should return false, because any document of my database match that all ocurrences of the input is in any document.

The query should find in contracts and formats all inputs values of input array.

Can anyone help me please?. I have tried with $elemMatch, $nor and $in, $unwind but unsatisfactory result.

Thanks to all for your time.